# onsubmit() fires but makes no changes to element style on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html, asp.net, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to show a modal window on top of the screen when user submits the form.
I want to disable form (show some loading icon) to show that button was clicked and action is being processed, because sometimes on mobile it's not so clear for our users

On PC browsers (Firefox, IE, Opera) everything works fine, but on Android or WP 8.1 div overlay is not shown after submitting the form.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue? 
Maybe some other approach?

My sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowLoadingPanel() {
            document.getElementById('loadingPanel').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block'
        }
 </script>

<body>
 <div id="loadingPanel" class="loadingPanelStyle"></div>
 <div id="overlay" class="blackOverlay">    </div>
 <form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return ShowLoadingPanel();">
    //some content
     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="xNext" Text="Next" OnClick="xNext_Click" />
 </form>
</body>
```

And some CSS for modal window

```
.loadingPanelStyle
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background:url(../img/load2.gif) no-repeat center center;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    font-size: small;
    z-index: 1002;
    overflow: auto;
}

.blackOverlay
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: .80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

Comment: you have a typo on line 3, missing " ' " before "block"

Comment: Thanks for noticing, but it was only typo in my question.

Comment: does the page reload when you submit on your mobile device?

Comment: Yes, it reloads, but modal form is not showing even for a minute.

Comment: It's still not working on mobile, but also stopped working on PC browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hints from @Velimir Tchatchevsky I found solution which is working.

```
function ShowLoadingPanel() {
        document.getElementById('loadingPanel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';

        setTimeout(function(){ 
            document.getElementById('form1').submit();
        }, 100);
        return false;
}
```

But it's weird that on WP8.1 (Internet Explorer) and Android 4 (Default browser) it's mandatory to use setTimeout() function, to postpone submit action.
Is it some mobile optimization or what?
Thank you all for help!

Answer (score -1):

You should put `.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function ShowLoadingPanel(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById('loadingPanel').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block'
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    $(this).submit(); 
                }, 3000);
            }
     </script>
```

Comment: But I want form to submit. I want to disable form (show some loading icon) to show that button was clicked and action is being processed, because sometimes on mobile it's not so clear for our users.

Comment: that would submit it after 3sec of showing the loadingPanel

Comment: How to pass this e parameter?? I'm relatively new to JS

Comment: onsubmit="return ShowLoadingPanel(this);"

Answer (score -1):

Please try with this. Remove javascript and add jquery function.

```
$("#loadingPanel").show();

$("#overlay").show();
```

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery unless it's impossible to make it work without it

Comment: Why u make minus marking? If you don't use than make comment.

Comment: It wasn't me :D Is it possible to check who doesn't like post/comment?

Comment: Ok. Buddy,. No problem

Comment: No. It is not possible.

Comment: I tried your solution with jQuery 1.11.3. But still no luck on Windows Phone 8.1 (Internet Explorer) and Android (Default browser)